# ActionLink Fails to Render within "if" Block

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.Net MVC 4 view that is supposed to conditionally render an ActionLink.  However, the ActionLink does not render in the final output.  To diagnose the issue, I added text before and after the desired ActionLink, and also duplicated the ActionLink code outside the `if` body.

The result is that the ActionLink code outside of the `if` body, as well as the before/after text, renders but not the ActionLink I actually want.

```
@Html.ActionLink("NEXT", "_NextPage")

@if (true /*!Model.IsFinalPage*/) {
    <text>Pre</text>
    Html.ActionLink("NEXT", "_NextPage");
    <text>Post</text> 
}
```

Output:

NEXT Pre Post

(NEXT is an appropriate link)

Comment: Did you try  putting the @ before Html.ActionLink, i.e.: @Html.ActionLink("NEXT", "_NextPage")? I don't think it would output without it.

Comment: Heh, that did it... but why?  I thought the "@" introduces a C# code block, but clearly that line is already being interpreted as C# else it would be emitted as HTML.

Comment: In razor, plain-old Html.ActionLink *returns* the html-string, but it doesn't get written to he buffer without the @. so @Html.ActionLink would be the same as   Response.Write Html.ActionLink

Comment: or rather: Response.Write(Html.ActionLink);

Comment: If you want to change that comment into a response, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The action-link needs the @ to work here.

In razor, plain-old Html.ActionLink *returns* the html-string, but it doesn't get written to he buffer without the @. so

```
@Html.ActionLink
```

would be the same as

```
Response.Write(Html.ActionLink);
```